# Timout ao consultar entre 2 intervalos de data

Tags: c#, sql-server, expressões-lambda

Tenho uma query onde faço uma consulta entre 2 intervalos de datas. 
Nessas datas, aplico o `DbFunctions.TruncateTime` para filtrar as buscas apenas pelas datas, ignorando o horário.

> Obs: são campos DateTime

```
.Where(p => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(p.DataCadastro) >= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(dataInicial) && 
            DbFunctions.TruncateTime(p.DataCadastro) <= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(dataFinal));
```

Porém, ao utilizar o `DbFunctions.TruncateTime` a requisição sempre me retorna:

> Tempo Limite de Execução Expirado.  O período de tempo limite terminou
>   antes da conclusão da operação ou o servidor não está respondendo.

Comment: Timeout normalmente indica uma consulta válida. Sua tabela tem muitos registros? Tem índice nesse campo de data?

Comment: Quando realizo a mesma consulta sem o TruncateTime, consigo fazer as consultas. Porém por ser DateTime, alguns registros deixa de vim nessa lista.

Comment: Essas funções são mapeadas internamente em cada provedor para outras funções e pode ser que isso está deixando lento o suficiente para dar o timeout. Já tentou usar a dataInicial com hora "00:00:00" e a final com hora "23:59:59" e comparar direto ao invés de truncar o campo DataCadastro para Date?

Comment: @Pagotti, não cheguei a comparar dessa forma, mas vou testar.

Comment: @Pagotti, seria definindo um timeSpan e concatenando com o date?

Comment: TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(23, 59, 59);

(p => p.DataCadastro>= dataInicial.Date + ts)

Comment: Pode ser assim mas faz isso fora da função lambda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma sugestão:

```
var dataIni = dataInicial.Date + new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
var dataFin = dataFinal.Date + new TimeSpan(23, 59, 59);

expressao.Where(p => p.DataCadastro >= dataIni && 
                     p.DataCadastro <= dataFin);
```

Como o erro é de timeout e a função de TruncateTime é traduzida internamente pelo banco de dados para algo que não é possível determinar pelo texto da pergunta, é provável que algo nessa transformação possa estar deixando a consulta muito lenta, sem poder usar algum índice, e por isso ocorre o timeout.

Assim, uma tentativa é continuar fazendo uma comparação com 2 valores do tipo DateTime colocando a hora fixa nos extremos do dia.

Comment: Obrigadão, @Pagotti

Answer (score -1):

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
.Where(p => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(p.DataCadastro) >= dataInicial.Date
         && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(p.DataCadastro) <= dataFinal.Date);
```

Comment: Dessa forma não vai. Foi a primeira que testei.

Comment: O que acontece?

Comment: "The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported."

Comment: @PedroPaulo EntityFunctions é para versões do EF menores que 5. A única coisa que muda é a função em si, nunca seria a causa de um timeout.